# What is Cold And Hot definition in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I've been read [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription) (by  SIMON BASLÉ)

When Publisher is nothing happens until you subscribe => is Cold

When Publisher is nothing happens until you subscribe… until something does => is Hot

Everything is good until I read Reactor Doc.

> One example of the few hot operators in Reactor is just: It directly captures the value at assembly time and replays it to anybody subscribing to it later.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold

"just" is hot operators ? Anything get value at assembly time means hot ?So "Flux.fromIterable(iterable)" is hot too ? How could I know publishers will get vlaue at assembly time?  I'm so confused.

Please tell me is there any cold operators ?  Thanks a lot !

Comment: The point being _when is the data generated_? With `just` the data is generated before any subscriber. With `fromIterable` the `Iterator` is requested and iterated for each subscriber.

Comment: I know what you mean. Thanks for answering.  One more question, how could I know? Is "just" the only one hot operator ?

Comment: I don't think I would consider `just` a hot operator just b/c it captures the data immediately. I don't see any way for a subscriber to get only some of the elements of the stream versus getting them all whenever a subscriber subscribes. I think it is a bad example.

Comment: I agree with you. `just` make things complicated. Maybe I think too much.